# How do you properly install an ASP.NET MVC app as a child of another MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a main website app written in ASP.NET's MVC 3.  Now, what I would like to do on occasion, is add a subdirectory, mark it as an application and run a whole different MVC 3 app from that directory.  For instance, my site is at http://sol3.net.  I am working on a small MVC app for a client and I'd like to publish it on my site so he can take a look at the progress, offer feedback, etc.  So, their site would be at http://sol3.net/projectA.  Having done this with a test app all I am getting is a 500 error.

Are there any best practices on how to set this up?

And yes, I already know about web.config inheritance problems.  Fortunately my web.configs are not too large and I think I have most everything handled there.

---

NOTE:  What I am trying to do is temporarily run a MVC app (App B) from within an app folder on an already active site (App A).  App A and App B do not share anything in common and App B will eventually be moved to its own hosting site.

---

NOTE #2:  The Answer...

I believe it is IIS7 and higher that allows you to add a redirection in your root web.config.  Here is what I ended up doing instead of doing it via IIS Manager:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="APP 1 - Sub domain to sub folder" enabled="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?app1\.sol3\.net$" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="app1/{R:1}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Would using [areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793.aspx) help solve your problem?

Comment: The app is not related in any way so no, areas would not help in this situation.

Comment: What about using a subdomain for your client. For example, http://client.yourcompany.com/

Comment: Using a sub-domain would be cool.  I don't have access to editing the web site headers though.  But this would be my first choice with my above question being my second choice.

Comment: why can you host the second site in a virtual folder in the primary app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add a subdomain via an alias in your DNS records.  Some registrars will let you do this yourself, but some sell this as a feature.  A whois on your domain says it's registered with GoDaddy.  Check this out.  http://help.godaddy.com/article/4652#addsubdomain1

Edit - OrcsWeb allows for remote management of your web site via IIS 7 Manager.  This should allow you to edit the host header.  http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/brad/iis-7-manager-for-remote-administration-installing-and-connecting-to-a-site/

Comment: My domain is from GoDaddy, I use NO-IP.com to manage DNS and yes, I can add a sub-domain via NO-IP's dashboard.  My files reside on OrcsWeb and I have not found a way to let IIS know that it should have a host header.

Comment: Found out that I can issue a redirect from my main web.config.  (See my question above where I entered a note).  Now tracking down some mundane issues.